# Call a function multiple times with different argument for date

Tags: r, loop, function, for-loop

I need to call the same function 10 times, each time with a different year for the end date argument. For example, the end date needs to start as "2011-01-01", then "2012-01-01", then "2013-01-01", etc. How do I loop this function but change the one argument until the last end date is "2020-01-01"?

```
VI <- mt_subset(product = "MOD13Q1",
                band = "250m_16_days_NDVI",
                lon = 28.5826,
                lat = 1.4368,
                start = "2010-01-01",
                end = "2011-01-01",
                km_lr = 20,
                km_ab = 20,
                site_name = "Ituri test",
                internal = TRUE,
                progress = TRUE)
```

Comment: Take a look at `do.call`. This is what it lives for. I would warn though, hitting the MODIS server up in sequential calls is a sure way to get timed out. I would highly recommend capturing errors, eg., failed download. In this way you can figure out where it failed in downloading data without slogging through the in disk results. You can do this with `tryCatch` in your looping or call structure. In a for loop you could see a failed download and then move to the next one, which works.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans do.call? this is more like a plain `for` or `lapply` loop isn't it?

Comment: @Spacedman, yes but you can split out the parameters into a list the use `do.call` with `lapply` and really abbrevte the code. I guess that does negate the advice of using `tryCatch`

Comment: @JeffreyEvans no I don't see it. `do.call(what, args)`  is `what(args[1], args[2], args[3],...etc...)`. How is that going to call `mt_subset` several times? Or are you thinking of `do.call(stack, lapply(dates, function(date){mt_subset(..date..)}))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to create a vector of years to iterate on and then assign the value of mt_subset to different objects

```
# first create the vector of the years
years = c()
for(i in 2011:2020) { 
years = c(years, sprintf("%s-01-01", i))
  }
print(years) # check the vector


# iterate
for(i in 1:(length(years) - 1)) { 
  nam = paste("VI", i, sep = "_") # create names for the objects
  assign(nam) <- mt_subset(product = "MOD13Q1",
                  band = "250m_16_days_NDVI",
                  lon = 28.5826,
                  lat = 1.4368,
                  start = years[i],
                  end = years[i + 1],
                  km_lr = 20,
                  km_ab = 20,
                  site_name = "Ituri test",
                  internal = TRUE,
                  progress = TRUE)
 
}
```

Comment: Using `assign` can be a dangerous thing in the global environment and should not be recommended on code solutions. It would be safer to assign results to something like a list object.

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful. I just took out assign, and it served my purposes well. Thank you again. @JeffreyEvans